# Convert Number to Arabic words Instead of English

Tags: java

I have a requirement to convert digit to words in Arabic. I have already found the logic to convert from Digit to English words but not in arabic except few example which only support upto thousand. So, is there any library available to convert the digit to Arabic words?

Note - I can not use google translate or any online API.